# Nginx as reverse proxy: how to properly configure gateway timeout?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, timeout, reverse-proxy

We have configured **Nginx** as a reverse proxy to an Apache server farm, but I'm running into trouble with the gateway timeouts.

Our Goal in human readable form is: "Deliver a request within one second, but if it really takes longer, deliver anyway", which for me translates into "Try the first Apache server in upstream for max 500ms. If we get a timeout / an error, try the next one and so on until we finally succeed."

Now our relevant configuration is this:

```
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass         http://apache$request_uri;

    proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    proxy_read_timeout 2s;

}

[...]

upstream apache {
 server 127.0.0.1:8001          max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s;
 server 10.1.x.x:8001           max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s backup;
 server 10.1.x.x:8001           max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s backup;
 server 10.1.x.x:8001           max_fails=1 fail_timeout=10s backup;
}
```

The problem here is that nginx seems to misunderstand this as "Try to get a response from the whole upstream cluster within one second and deliver a 50X error if we don't - without any limit on how long to try any upstream server", which is obviously not what we had in mind.

Is there any way to get nginx to do what we want?

Comment: Nginx isn't "misunderstanding", proxy_connect_timeout applies to the entire upstream, so you are explicitly telling Nginx to only try for 1s before failing. Also, your "human readable" goal doesn't say much except "take as long as you like".

Comment: proxy_read_timeout 500ms and max_fails=0 should work better.

Comment: There's no way to tell nginx "deliver in one second, but if it takes longer it's probably okay". Because even in human-readable form this would be "it's okay if the wait will be infinite". So far you failed to define border condition for timeout, and that's why this question has no answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is:

`max_fails=0`

and

`proxy_next_upstream = timeout`

per the docs:

> **max_fails**=number
>
> sets the number of unsuccessful attempts to
>   communicate with the server that should happen in the duration set by
>   the fail_timeout parameter to consider the server unavailable for a
>   duration also set by the fail_timeout parameter. By default, the
>   number of unsuccessful attempts is set to 1. The zero value disables
>   the accounting of attempts. What is considered an unsuccessful attempt
>   is defined by the proxy_next_upstream, fastcgi_next_upstream,
>   uwsgi_next_upstream, scgi_next_upstream, and memcached_next_upstream
>   directives.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

and:

> Syntax:   **proxy_next_upstream** error | timeout | invalid_header |
>   http_500 | http_502 | http_503 | http_504 | http_403 | http_404 |
>   non_idempotent | off ...; Default:     proxy_next_upstream error timeout;
>
> Context:  http, server, location Specifies in which cases a request
>   should be passed to the next server:
>
> **error**
>
> an error occurred while establishing a connection with the
>   server, passing a request to it, or reading the response header;
>
> **timeout**
>
> a timeout has occurred while establishing a connection with
>   the server, passing a request to it, or reading the response header;

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream