# Proxy route request to other endpoint if timeout

Tags: proxy

How can I implement a proxy that routes requests to a cloud endpoint, but routes the request to an endpoint from a local server if a - configured - timeout happened?

As far as I understand, this is kind of a reverse proxy configuration. The answer could be a good documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx as reverse proxy: how to properly configure gateway timeout?](https://serverfault.com/questions/421347/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-how-to-properly-configure-gateway-timeout)